# Python's decimal module capping precision at 50 even though its set to 130, how to fix this?

Tags: python

I am trying to define the PI constant with 128 digits of accuracy (after the decimal point). This is totally overkill for accuracy and I am aware of this. The code I'm using is:

```py
from decimal import getcontext, Decimal
getcontext().prec = 130
PI = Decimal(3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460)
print(PI)
```

The output of this is

> 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875

which isn't even in my defined decimal. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using a `float` as the input, so the precision is limited by floating point.

Use a string instead.

```
PI = Decimal('3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460')
```

Comment: Thanks so much, new to Decimal module so not that sure with it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the Decimal module. A module can't change how function arguments are parsed.

Comment: If the digits are lost when you type the float, `Decimal` can't add them back.